# Why isn't this provide and yield not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yield

Trying to pass these into the form.

```
<% provide(:title,"Edit Type") %>
<% provide(:content,"Edit Type") %>
<% provide(:button,"Update") %>
<% provide(:link,"form_for(@type, url: product_type_path, method: :patch)") %>  <!-- edit for product_type model(@type) url: go to product_type controller with update action -->
<%= render 'form' %>
```

## _form.html.erb

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= yield(:link) do |f| %>  
        <h3><%= yield(:content) %></h3>
        <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

        <%= f.label :value %>
        <%= f.number_field :value, class: 'form-control' %>

        <%= f.submit yield(:button), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

The error the is generated is either implicit symbol conversion to integer or something related to end of keyword ensure.

What is wrong in this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't pass forms like that.

Comment: so is it bad to use lot of provide and yield? @SergioTulentsev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This complex helper under `:link` isn't going to work as you expect...

```
<% provide(:link,"form_for(@type, url: product_type_path, method: :patch)")
```

All this will do is render the following string in your view...

> form_for(@type, url: product_type_path, method: :patch)

You can't even do `<%= eval(yield :link) %>` because you don't have a block, and if you modified your string to include `do |f|` it wouldn't recognise it as the start of a block anyway.

Generally, I think what you want to do is impossible, and even if you could make it work, it would be a really bad idea in terms of readability, and possibly security.

The `provide` and `content_for` are a nice way to store and deliver simple markup to various views, but the markup has to be self contained, and can't be (for example) the beginning of a block.

You *could* possibly use it to store the raw `<form ... >` information, but I can't see it being used with the `form_for` helper.

Comment: sure , thanks for letting me know. I would have wasted time tinkering around if you hadn't answered.